# Path-integral Monte Carlo to simulate motion of an atom in one-dimensional harmonic potential

Tags: python, physics, montecarlo

I am trying to simulate the motion of an atom in a one-dimensional harmonic potential. I want to calculate the position of an atom in the harmonic potential and then plot the position with respect to an (arbitrary) time unit. I want to do the simulation using the path-integral Monte Carlo method (PIMC).

PIMC is a method, where one quantum particle is described by P "beads", where P is the so-called Trotter number. This way we obtain a partition function of an isomorphic classical system, a "necklace/ring polymer" of P beads, all of which experience the same potential energy.

Pseudocode for Metropolis MC could be as follows:

```
Put N*P particles at random positions;
REPEAT
    for i=1 to P DO
        select random P;
        select one of the N particles at P at random;
        generate random displacement of that particle;
        compute r = exp(-delta_tau*(H_new - H_old));
        accept/reject the displacement with normal Metropolis check;
    end for;
UNTIL FINISHED
```

The code that I have written so far generates only sparse points, it does not seem to simulate the position properly. If anyone knows the physics/PIMC method, can you help me to fix this code? I guess it should find some kind of equilibrium point, but the plot only shows a few individual points.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def V(x, k=54.869):
    """
    1D potential for quantum harmonic oscillator.
    k = harmonic force constant
    x = position
    """
    return 1/2*k*x**2

def move(x, drmax):
    """
    Simple MC move.
    x = position (1D)
    drmax = maximum displacement parameter
    """
    ran = random.uniform(0, 1)
    pos = x + (ran - 0.5)*drmax
    return pos
    
def metropolis_check(r_old, r_new, k, kB, T):
    """
    Check wheter to accept or reject trial move.
    T = temperature
    kB = Boltzmann constant
    """
    r = math.nan
    if V(k, r_new) < V(k, r_old):
        r = r_new
    else:
        deltaV = V(k, r_new) - V(k, r_old)
        boltzmann = np.exp(-deltaV/(kB*T))
        ran = random.uniform(0, 1)
        if boltzmann > ran:
            r = r_new
        else:
            r = r_old
    return r
    
def PIMC(N, P, T):    
    """
    Metropolis Monte Carlo algorithm.
    N = number of particles
    P = number of beads per particle
    T = temperature
    """
    drmax = 1
    delta_time_slice = 10**(-6)
    k = 54.869 # harmonic force constant
    kB = 1.380649*10**(-23) #Boltzmann constant
    
    #put the NP particles at random positions
    positions = random.sample(range(-N*P, N*P), N*P)
    times = list(np.zeros(len(positions)))
    H = list(map(V, positions))
    
    for j in range(10): # loop so many times that position converges (?)
        for i in range(P):
            # first select time slice P at random
            # then select one of the N particles at time slice P at random
            time_slice = random.choice(range(P))
            times.append(time_slice)
            part = random.choice(range(N))
            bead = positions[time_slice]

            # generate random displacement of that bead (simple MC move)
            x = move(bead, drmax)
            H_old = H[i]
            H_new = V(k, x)
            H[i] = H_new
            r_old = positions[i - 1]
            r_new = np.exp(-delta_time_slice*(H_old - H_new))

            # accept or reject the displacement with metropolis check     
            r = metropolis_check(r_old, r_new, k, kB, T)
            positions.append(r)

    return positions, times

positions, times = PIMC(1, 5, 300)
plt.scatter(times, positions)
plt.ylabel("positions")
plt.xlabel("time")
```

Comment: Your problem is quite complex, can you please provide more details on this phrase: "The code that I have written so far generates only sparse points, it does not seem to simulate the position properly" what is the current behavior and what is the correct behavior? Did you test this on the simplest possible toy problem as a first test? can you please include the plot generated now and a hand drawn correct plot?